# Need python life saving

Tags: python

Get a large, representative quantity of English text into your program.
Process that text (line by line) to create individual counts for each letter of the English alphabet.
Display the results of the “letter counting” process in a bar plot

so far i have got this and i cant figure out how to go from here:

```
import urllib.request
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://students.healthinformaticshub.ca/jane-austen-sense-n-sensibility.txt', context=ctx)
page_content = response.read()
lines = page_content.decode(encoding='UTF-8').split('\n')

line_num = 1

# loop thru line by line:
for line in lines:
    print('Line ' + str(line_num) + ': ' + line.strip())
    line_num = line_num + 1

while
if('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z')

stats[ch - 'a'].count++;

else if('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z')

stats[ch - 'A'].count++;
}

inputfile.close();
```

Comment: its imposible to understand your question with your indentation  ... are you meant to do a bar plot for each line? are you meant to do one bar plot for all the text?

Comment: There are a number of basic syntax errors in this code. I would start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: part of the problem is that you copied and pasted c/c++ code into a .py file (alright it might be php or something ... but my guess is c/c++)

Comment: im meant to do a bar plot on probability for each alphabet character

Comment: well and the code is what the teacher told us to use as a layout

Comment: but okay ill check it out

Comment: It is hard to help if you don't have a basic understanding of the language you are trying to get help on, please read the **documentation** for python [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/), then read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ask a complete question.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is count letter characters, you don't need to split the text into separate lines.  The number of A's is going to be the same whether you split it into lines or not.

```
## Get the line
page_content = response.read()

## Make everything lowercase (so A and a are the same)
page_content = page_content.lower()

## Remove non letter characters
letters = [ch for ch in page_content if ch.isalpha()]
```

You now have just the letters.  I'll let you figure out how to plot.

Hope this helps!